# is it possible to get the tag history in an ECR (the aws docker registry) repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecr

I use tags to mark the currently deployed version, and I want to know if it's possible to query which image was tagged at a certain time with a specific label.

While it's possible to keep track of these externally, having this option appears more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current tags but getting the history of tags is not possible.

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name test-nginx
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageTag": "1.0",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:31641ee69cxxx1ca550a754376e9077f6f9134ad41e27"
        },
        {
            "imageTag": "latest",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:31641ee69cda92e0xxx9077f6f9134ad41e27"
        }
    ]
}
```